# Filter multiple columns with one input via pipes | angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to filter an array of objects with user input. I have completed this however only if I specify the property name to filter values on. How would I filter *every* properties values?

**Pipe:**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'columns' })

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(columns: any, filterText: any): any {
    if (filterText == null) return columns;
    return columns.filter(function(column) {
      return column.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="filterText" type="text">

<tr *ngFor='let office of offices | columns: filterText'>
  <td><input type="checkbox" checked class="i-checks" name="input[]"></td>
  <td>{{ office.officeId }}</td>
  <td>{{ office.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ office.createdAt | date:'longDate'}}</td>
  <td>{{ office.noOfPhones }}</td>
  <td>{{ office.address }}</td>
  <td>{{ office.region }}</td>
  <td>{{ office.status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values) to obtain the list of all values of your column and return true if one value or much match the search :

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(columns: any, filterText: any): any {
    if (filterText == null) return columns;

    // we lowercase here to avoir doing it multiple time
    filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();

    return columns.filter(function(column) {
        return Object.values(column)
                     .some(value => value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
    });
  }
}
```

Caution: The will throw error if some values are not string, so you should add a check on the value.toLowerCase();

Caution 2: Will not work on Internet explorer since Object.values is not implemented, but [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys) is implemented since IE9

so you could use

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(columns: any, filterText: any): any {
        if (filterText == null) return columns;

        // we lowercase here to avoir doing it multiple time
        filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();

        return columns.filter(function(column) {
            return Object.keys(column)
                         .some(key => column[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1);
        });
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps